# htaccess redirect to subdirectory by default, but open main site from link in subdirectory site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is my example site

`http://www.example.com/` - (main site, in English)

`http://example.com/mylang/` - (site in my language)

Both the sites run with multiple installation of wordpress.

Now, when user enter my website, he must be redirected to `http://example.com/mylang/` and there is a link to go to main site `http://www.example.com/` if the user wants to see.

How can I do with `.htaccess`? I am open to get other (`php` or `javascript` redirect) solutions also.

Comment: Whats the status of this question?

Answer (score 1):

On `main site` check if a session is set, if not redirect. (Note this must be done before any output is sent)

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['been_here'])) {
     header('Location: http://example.com/mylang/');
     exit();
}
```

On the `mylang` set the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['been_here'] = 1;
```

The duration of this session won't redirect on front page visits.

Comment: Initially this worked for me. Thanks. But as I have enabled auto updates in WordPress, index.php files restores or uppdates and my codes goes away. So what I did was, replicated wp in my localhost as backup, reinstalled wp mylang as default on the server

Answer (score 0):

You should put below code inside .htaccess of root folder of main site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/mylang [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This works as `http://example.com` to `http://example.com/mylang`. But when clicked for `http://example.com` from `http://example.com/mylang` it again redirects to  `http://example.com/mylang`. I cant got main site. Please help me.